# Doubt regarding what kind of questions I can ask on meta

Tags: discussion, support

Suppose in the actual math stackexchange site, I got my answer down voted.

I actually was pretty satisfied with my answer and was pretty down on not getting any upvotes, and then I got a downvote.

Is it okay to ask people on meta for suggestions to my answer or any reason that it is not nice? (As the downvoter chose not to comment on it).

I had this doubt, but I didnt know where I could ask to get it clarified, so I felt it right to post it here. So I am really sorry if I wasn't supposed to.

Comment: You can ask on chat, an in particular in [this room](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/43593/constructive-feedback). Questions like the one you want to ask are regularly asked and answered on meta. However, if everyone did this this would take over meta.

Comment: As a rule check whether the question as well as other answers were downvoted (as of now your reputation does not allow you to see vote counts, but a negative overall score necessarily indicates downvote). Answers to many low quality questions are often downvoted.

Comment: @user1729 Thanks a lot for your help! Appreciate it.

Comment: @ParamanandSingh So if I felt my answer was actually helpful but gained a negative overall score (Which in my case was the only vote on it), would that mean that my answer was actually low quality and I need to work more on it?

Comment: My last comment was meant to give a possible reason for downvote. Often a good answer to a poor question gets downvoted because some people want to discourage answering poor questions. So a downvote on an answer may not necessarily indicate that answer is of low quality.

Comment: @ParamanandSingh Okay noted! Thank you so much!